# How does this TypeScript function parameter work

Tags: typescript

I found this code online and trying to understand it.

```
public searchFunctionFactory($index: any): (text: Observable<string>) => Observable<any[]> {


    //Create a function that considers the specified $index parameter value
    let getCities = (text$: Observable<string>) => 
        text$
            .debounceTime(300)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap( query => {

                //some logic involving $index here
                //...

                //query.length < 2 ? [] : this.apiService.getCities(query).catch(() => {
                //return Observable.of([]);
            });

    //Return that "custom" function, which will in turn be called by the ngbTypescript component
    return getCities;
}
```

My question revolves around the method signature.

```
public searchFunctionFactory($index: any): (text: Observable<string>) => Observable<any[]>
```

I understand

`$index: any` is an input parameter of type Any.

The function returns Observable an observable of any.

But what is 
`: (text: Observable<string>)`

Is it a second parameter?

If its a second parameter shouldn't it be

```
public searchFunctionFactory($index: any ,text: Observable<string>) => Observable<any[]>
```

Comment: That is actually a function that returns a function, and it is TypeScript code, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indicates that the return value of the `searchFunctionFactory` function is a function which takes a parameter of `text`, whose type is `Observable<string>`, and calling *that* function returns an `Observable<any[]>`. It's a higher-order function.

```
public searchFunctionFactory($index: any): (text: Observable<string>) => Observable<any[]> {
                        /*   ^^^^^^^^^^^   searchFunctionFactory parameter */
public searchFunctionFactory($index: any): (text: Observable<string>) => Observable<any[]> {
  /* searchFunctionFactory return value     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
```

As comment notes, this is not Javascript syntax, but Typescript syntax.

So, if you call

```
const result = searchFunctionFactory(someVar);
```

`result` will be of the type

```
(text: Observable<string>) => Observable<any[]>
```

and you could then call it with

```
const resultTwo = result(someOtherVar)
```

to get a value whose type is `Observable<any[]>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation .can i call it like this const result = searchFunctionFactory(someVar)(someOtherVar)()

Comment: Don't think so. You could do `searchFunctionFactory(someVar)(someOtherVar)`, thereby calling the returned function immediately, but that returned function does not return a function as well (it returns an Observable), so you couldn't call it too. `const observableOfAny = searchFunctionFactory(someVar)(someOtherVar)`

Comment: Hi Thanks again so it would be on the lines of const observableOfAny = searchFunctionFactory(someVar) and then the usual routine  observableOfAny.subscribe(() => do something) ?

Comment: What `searchFunctionFactory` returns is a function, not a observerable - you'd have to call the returned function to get the observable of any. `searchFunctionFactory(someVar)(someOtherVar)` and *then* you can call `.subscribe` or whatever you want on that observable